# HttpContext is null in abstract class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set a session inside a abstract class which is already written. What I am trying to do is;
First I try to check the method type either is get or post. If it is GET method then set the session.

here is the code:

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractController : Controller
{
    public BaseAbstractController()
    {
        if (this.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "GET")
        {
            this.HttpContext.Session["testsession"] = this.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, I get the Null exception error and it is because HTTPContext value is null.

Right now there is only one MVC controller that extends from abstract controller.

Comment: When and from where is it  called?

Comment: Nothing call this method. Another controller just extends from it.

Comment: Yes, and that controller's contructor calls it's base constructor. But when is that controller initialized and from where? Having said that, i'm not that familiar with MVC. But obviously at that point there is no current `HttpContext` or `HttpContext.Request`. Use the debugger, set a breakpoint in the first line of the constructor.

Comment: My guess is, the MVC or some dependency injector is doing it. May be I need to override execute/initialize function to make the httpcontext work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better not doing that in constructor, as constructor should only construct the instance if possible. You can override `OnActionExecuting` instead.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    var req = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    if (req.HttpMethod == "GET")
    {
        filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["testsession"] = req.Url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `HttpContext` property within `Controller` that you're referencing isn't set until AFTER the controller has been instansiated - meaning it will not be available within your abstract classes' constructor.

If you need to access the `HttpContext` object then your best bet is to reference the static instance directly like so: `System.Web.HttpContext`

```
public abstract class BaseAbstractController : Controller
{
    public BaseAbstractController()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "GET")
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["testsession"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To respond to your comment, if you're trying to access the `HttpContext` within `OnActionExecuted` then you should access it via the request context within the `ActionExecutedContext` argument like this:

```
protected virtual void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var context = filterContext.HttpContext;
}
```

The difference is that at this point the controller has been instantiated and the base controller's `HttpContext` property has been set. Ultimately all the .NET MVC framework is doing is referencing the `System.Web.HttpContext` static instance from `Controller.HttpContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But what if I override Execute or some other function like OnActionExecuted of CONTROLLER inside the abstract controller and then use the HTTPcontext and setting of session?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is not available in OWIN self-host, so it is better to avoid using it.